# Struggling to override System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>.CreateChannel()

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.ios

I am getting the following `InvalidOperationException` while implementing a MonoTouch client for a simple WCF service exposed over HTTP.

> MonoTouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation. Override this method or its caller to return specific client proxy instance.

That comes from line 141 in [this file](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.ServiceModel/System.ServiceModel/ChannelFactory_1.cs).

So I need to override the method `CreateChannel()` on `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>` in my own subclass of ClientBase with an implementation that does not use dynamic code generation. The method returns an instance of `T`.

If I return a new instance of my service client, `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>` throws the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'MyServiceClient' to type 'System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel'` on the getter for `InnerChannel`.

I have no clear idea how to proceed from this point - any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a very simple interface - so I just wrote a simple client based on System.Net.WebClient, which worked perfectly and was about 10 lines of code.

Comment: I have the same issue, can you provide sample code to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Just build a really simple desktop client for the service, fire up Wireshark to see what happens on the wire, then replicate it using simple code that uses WebClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.100).aspx) in a simple way. Then hide this code somewhere in your MonoTouch solution, and when you eventually get this stuff working properly on MonoTouch, replace the WebClient-based implementation with the proper one.

Answer (score 1):

From the source, it looks like the framework cannot create a new instance of your channel via reflection, so it requires you override the method yourself.

Much of the WCF infrastructure is non-obvious, mostly due to its unusual use of generics (which only makes sense after you've been through the plumbing and back). In this case, the channel returned by `CreateChannel()` **must** be an `IClientChannel` (because you're on the client side of conversation). Ensure this interface is present on your channel and your error should go away (probably to be replaced by another problem).

Comment: If you need more assistance, post your override of `CreateChannel()`

Comment: Implementing IClientChannel looks like a nightmare. I've switched to creating a 2.0-style Web Reference, let's see where we go from there.

Comment: You normally wouldn't create your own channel (unless you're doing something very specific that isn't supported by WCF). You should only be constructing a channel already provided by the WCF library - the selection of the type and configuration of the channel is the hard part.